# airflow error on db but task still is successful

Tags: airflow

I have an annoying internal error in airflow `2.5.1` that I am unable to detect what could be the reason:

```
(venv)$ airflow tasks test my_task sleep 2023-01-01
[2023-03-02 07:00:16,517] {dagbag.py:538} INFO - Filling up the DagBag from /opt/***/dags
[2023-03-02 07:00:16,957] {cleanup_db.py:149} ERROR - type object 'TaskFail' has no attribute 'execution_date'
/home/d5291029/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/airflow/models/param.py:67 RemovedInAirflow3Warning: The use of non-json-serializable params is deprecated and will be removed in a future release
/home/d5291029/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/airflow/cli/commands/task_command.py:159 RemovedInAirflow3Warning: Calling `DAG.create_dagrun()` without an explicit data interval is deprecated
```

Any ideas ? thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We've faced this issue when upgrading Airflow to 2.3 since the `execution_date` attribute has been removed from `TaskFail`. See the [Airflow 2.3 changelog](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/release_notes.html#airflow-2-3-0-2022-04-30).

As the changelog states, change your reference from `TaskFail.execution_date` to `TaskFail.dag_id` when defining DAGs.